# Evaluation of Clustering in Scikit-learn According to Pairs

Tags: cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I use scikit-learn to cluster my data, and wish to evaluate the results.

I wonder if there is a built-in function that calculates TP, TN, FP, FN according to pairs of documents, as explained in *Introduction to Information Retrieval, Ch.16, p.359 (http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/16flat.pdf)*?

Thanks, 
Alon

Comment: Like a [confusion matrix](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix)?

Comment: @EdChum confusion matrix makes sense for classification, not for clustering. See Wikipedia, Cluster analysis, section evaluation.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse but wouldn't you be able to calculate the TP/TN/FP and FN from a confusion matrix?

Comment: @EdChum how do you compute a confusion matrix when you don't have classes on one axis, but clusters? There is no 1:1 correspondence between cluster and classes. That is why you work on *pairs* in clustering evaluation. See Wikipedia!

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Ah yes I see what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `sklearn.metrics.cluster` package, and `sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score`.

I don't know if they expose the 2 by 2 matrix, but there is functionality to compute some of the most popular evaluation metrics.

Comment: Thanks. 
But I think the implementation does not calculate the scores according to pairs, and therefore produces values that do not fit my expectations.

Comment: The Rand index (and ARI) are defined on the pairs. So what is it computing then, if not pairs?

Comment: True, I meant that other popular evaluation metrics are not calculated according to pairs (like f1_score), as suggested in the book above.